# Symfony Doctrine EntityManager not refreshing properly

Tags: php, symfony, websocket, doctrine, ratchet

I have a ratchet WebSocket server, whose `entityManager` is initialized from the backend. However, if some changes happen from one of the front-ends since the state of the `entityManager` of the WebSocket server is different from the backend, the new changes are not reflected in the data that is served by the WebSocket server.

For this purpose, I wrote some listeners on the backend that listen for changes in these entities in and then send a request to the server like so:

```
public function postUpdate(Room $entity, LifecycleEventArgs $_)
{
    try {
        Loop::run(function() use ($entityName, $id) {
        $conn = yield connect('ws://localhost:8080');
        yield $conn->send(json_encode(['message' => $entityName, 'data' => ['duid' => $id]]));
        $conn->close();});
    } catch (Exception $e) {}
}
```

I then fetch the entity in the WebSocket server and simply refresh it, like so:

```
function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
{
    try {
        $messageData = json_decode($msg);
        switch ($messageData->message) {
            case BookingSocketActions::ROOM_CHANGED_EVENT:
//                $room = $this->entityManager->getRepository('ResourcesBundle:Room')
//                                            ->find(['id' => $id]);
                $room = $this->entityManager->getRepository('ResourcesBundle:Room')
                                            ->findRoomDetailById($messageData->data->duid);
                // $this->entityManager->clear();
                $this->entityManager->refresh($room);
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $from->send($ex);
    }
}
```

Now here is the strange bug: The state of the `$entity` that is refreshed in the WebSocket server is always one behind the real changes of the entity. Suppose I change `$entity->name` from "1" to "2".

After the refresh `$entity->name` is still "1" on the WebSocket server. Only if I change it again to sth else, e.g. "3", will it change to "2" (after the refresh). If I change it to "4", it will go to "3" and so on.

The event is firing correctly from the backend and the entity is being fetched correctly on the server. It's just that `refresh()` works only on a second request (and therefore a second refresh) to the WebSocket server but not on the first.

I have tried even things like `$entityManager->merge($entity);` but no results.

I am on symfony 3.4, doctrine 2.7, and ratchet 0.4.3.

Comment: Do you have only one em configuration or multiple? Which DB? MySQL ? If so, take a look at your Master-Slave Replication.

Comment: This is in development, with no master-slave configuration.

Just one em configuration.

Comment: Do you have same behavior if you  explicitly "read" from DB. So instead of `->fetch($entity);` just `$this->entityManager->getRepository(...)->find($entity->getId());`

Comment: Yeah, same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing may be the event that is triggered to detect the update change.

If you you `postPersist` the entity wont have changed in the database. It will fire before `flush` happens.

You need to trigger the message to the socket server *after* the `flush`.

The second thing is to make sure that the entityManager instance detach and reload the `room` entity instance. That can be done with

`$this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->clear(Room::class);`

right before you query the entity again

```php
$this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->clear(Room::class);
$room = $this->entityManager
        ->getRepository('ResourcesBundle:Room')
        ->findRoomDetailById($messageData->data->duid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine uses the [identity map](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map)

The websocket server is a **daemon** and all cleanup tasks are the responsibility of the developer

**Use**

`\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::find` with the `$lockMode` argument = `\Doctrine\DBAL\LockMode::NONE`

OR

Call the `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::clean` method before `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::find`

Comment: I have already tried both with no results.

Comment: Show the code (char lim)

Comment: Updated the question with some websocket server side code

Comment: Where is entity attribute changes ?

Comment: That comes from the front-end and happens inside a Controller. After that, the event fires in order to update the `em` on the WebSocket server side.

Comment: Is second level cache (`doctrine.orm.entity_managers.name.second_level_cache`) enabled ?